# to find minimum missing number in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to find the minimum missing number of a column named (s_no) and the table named (test_table) in oracle and I write the following code..

```
select 
    min_s_no-1+level missing_number 
from (
    select min(s_no) min_s_no, max(s_no) max_s_no 
    from test_table
) connect by level <= max_s_no-min_s_no+1
minus
select s_no from test_table
;
```

it gives me all the missing number as a result. But I want to select the minimum
number. Can any one help me please.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Minimum missing number starting where? At zero? Or at the minimum number currently in the table?

Comment: @DavidFaber - The latter (judging by the code the OP posted).

Comment: @mathguy ... and on empty table returns `NULL` - to avoid using *negative infinity*:)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find the gaps is to use analytic functiions `lead` or `lag`. An example with `lag`:

```
with test_data as (
    select 1 num from dual union all
    select 4  from dual union all
    select 6  from dual union all
    select 8  from dual union all
    select 3  from dual union all
    select 9  from dual union all
    select 0  from dual
)
select min(gap) min_gap
from (
    select num, lag(num) over (order by num)+1 gap
    from test_data
    )
where num != gap
;    
MIN_GAP
------------------
                 2
```

More about how to find the gaps [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:69957990632697)

Comment: I'm glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Using analytical function `LEAD` you can get *the number from the next row* in ascending order. Comparing of this value with  with the *original number increased by 1* you get the missing values (if two numbers do not match).

To get the first missing value in ascending order is the same selecting the `MIN` value:

```
select 
num,
lead(num) over (order by num)  num_lead,
case when num + 1 != lead(num) over (order by num)  then num + 1 end as  missing_num
from test_data
order by num; 

       NUM   NUM_LEAD MISSING_NUM
---------- ---------- -----------
         4          5             
         5          6             
         6          9           7 
         9         10             
        10         13          11 
        13                        


-- first missing number = MIN missing number
select min(missing_num)
from (
select 
case when num + 1 != lead(num) over (order by num)  then num + 1 end as  missing_num
from test_data
);

MIN(MISSING_NUM)
----------------
               7
```

**ADDENDUM**

A good practice in writing SQL is to consider edge cases - here a table that contains a complete interval without holes. The first missing value will be the successor of the last number.

```
select nvl(min(missing_num),max(num)+1) first_missing_value
from (
select 
num,
case when num + 1 != lead(num) over (order by num)  then num + 1 end as  missing_num
from test_data
);
```

A complete table return no `MISSING_NUM`, so the original query return `NULL`. Using the `NVL` the expected result is provided.

Comment: You are welcome @MuhammadYasir, you can also accept the answer if it was helpfull:)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12.1 and above, MATCH_RECOGNIZE can do quick work of this kind of problems:

**Edited**. Initially I was picking the "next number" where a gap exists (in the example, the value `9`). But that is not what the OP wants, he wants the first missing number (`7` in this case). I edited to change the `measures` clause, to find the first missing number as requested.  **End Edit**

```
with test_data (num) as ( 
       select  4 from dual union all
       select  5 from dual union all
       select  6 from dual union all
       select  9 from dual union all
       select 10 from dual union all
       select 13 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; when you use the SQL query below,
-- replace test_data and num with your actual table and column names.
select result as num
from test_data
match_recognize (
  order by num
  measures last(b.num) + 1 as result
  pattern ( ^ a b* c )
  define b as num = prev(num) + 1,
         c as num > prev(num) + 1
)
;

NUM
---
  7
```